# which of the following statements are true and why?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

which of the following statements are true and why?

1. Any two irreducibles in any UFD are associates.
2. If $D$ is a PID, then $D[x]$ is a PID.
3. In any UFD, if $p|a$ for an irreducible $p$, then $p$ itself appears in every factorization of $a$.

---

can anyone help me to find the proofs and counter examples of the above as reasons.thanks for your time.

Comment: I have try to find counter examples but failed

Comment: It may be helpful to explain some of your ideas in the question, so that potential answerers can get an idea of what you know and where you might be confused.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is a UFD and in this ring, irreducible $\iff$ prime. So, if you take two distinct primes in $\mathbb{Z}$, are they associates?

Answer (score 2):

Hint 1) Look at $\Bbb Z$.

Hint 2) Look at $D=\Bbb Z$.

Hint 3) Let $u$ be any unit besides 1, and $q=pu$ is also prime. Now $p|q$. Does $p$ appear in the factorization of $q$ as just $q$? (I am not totally sure what counts as a factorization to you, so this is the best hint I can think of!)